# problems in constructing webmap using django leaflet with the data in database

Tags: django, leaflet, django-geoposition, django-leaflet

I have done my leaflet program using django-leaflet but the map is not displaying anything in output

Here is the code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as gismodels
class MushroomSpot(gismodels.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    id1=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    geom = gismodels.PointField()
    objects = gismodels.GeoManager()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
from .models import MushroomSpot

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='home'),
    url(r'^data.geojson$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=MushroomSpot), name='data'),    
]
```

index.html

```
{% load leaflet_tags %}
<html>
  <head>
    {% leaflet_js %}
    {% leaflet_css %}
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Weather Stations</h1>
    {% leaflet_map "main" callback="main_map_init" %}

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function main_map_init (map, options) {
            var dataurl = '{% url "data" %}';
    // Download GeoJSON via Ajax
    $.getJSON(dataurl, function (data) {
        // Add GeoJSON layer
        L.geoJson(data).addTo(map);
    });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

contents related to leaflet in settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR

LEAFLET_CONFIG = {
'DEFAULT_ZOOM': 6,
'MIN_ZOOM': 1,
'MAX_ZOOM': 20,
}
```

And I run the setup.py file which has

```
import csv
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

from mushrooms.models import MushroomSpot


csv_file = 'mycsv.csv'

def dms2dec(value):
    """
    Degres Minutes Seconds to Decimal degres
    """
    degres, minutes, seconds = value.split()
    #seconds, direction = seconds[:-1], seconds[-1]
    dec = float(degres) + float(minutes)/60 + float(seconds)/3600
    #if direction in ('S', 'W'):
    #    return -dec
    return dec

reader = csv.DictReader(open(csv_file), delimiter=",")
for line in reader:
    lng = dms2dec(line.pop('mlong'))
    lat = dms2dec(line.pop('mlat'))
    wmoid = int(line.pop('id'))
    name = line.pop('place').title()
    print(lng,lat)
    MushroomSpot(id1=wmoid, title=name, geom=Point(lng, lat)).save()
```

Please help me in getting the output map in screen
I dont know what is the error in it 
The csv file contains the data of about 8 cities in india
And I want the desired India map as an interactive webmap
Please let me to my desired output